# Elasticsearch - Reindex Picks Up No Documents

Tags: elasticsearch

ES newbie here. I want to move documents from one index to another, based on  a criterion. I've been using the Reindex API, specifically the version that takes a query - docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

I've been POST-ing the following query to `<root_es_uri>/_reindex`.

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": <EXISTING_SOURCE_INDEX>,
    "type": "_doc",
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "domain": <A SPECIFIC DOMAIN>
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": <AN EXISTING EMPTY INDEX>
  }
}
```

Running this yields the following:

```
{
    "took": 37,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 0,
    "updated": 0,
    "created": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 0,
    "version_conflicts": 0,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": []
}
```

So it "succeeds", but picks up no documents to move. When I run the query from the `_reindex` call against the `_search` endpoint of the source index, it returns all the documents I want moved, so I know my query is legitimate. At first I thought that perhaps the source index is configured not to allow reindexing like this, but I ran a `_reindex` command without the query (ie, copying all documents from the source index) and it worked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you run the query against the `_search` endpoint?

Comment: I did a POST to `<root_es_uri>/<source_index>/_search` with the a JSON body of  `{
 "query": {
      "term": {
        "domain": <A SPECIFIC DOMAIN>
      }
 }
}`. The reason for the POST instead of GET is that I'm using Postman, which does not allow passing JSON in the body of a GET. However, ES responds the same to a POST to the `_search` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The problem was the `_type` field on the request; the documents I was interested in moving did not have type `_doc`. Changing this field to the appropriate value solved the issue.